# Using a Plug-In AC/DC adapter Output's Negative as Earth GND

Tags: dc, emc, esd, earth

Now, this is not a general question about any plug-in 12V DC supply with a barrel connector output. They are all different. There are those without Eath GND wire in the AC power input, those with it, but without it being connected to the output negative, and then there are those with that connection of Earth GND to the DC Output Negative.

My specific power supply is the TRH70A120-02E01-Level-VI (yes this is their exact P/N) by Cincon.
The part is here
https://www.mouser.com/ProductDetail/Cincon/TRH70A120-02E01-Level-VI?qs=P8zB4ONU6fxl97c0YpS2Bw==
The datasheet is here
https://www.mouser.com/datasheet/2/75/Datasheet_TRH70A_series-2997934.pdf

It has a plain barrel connector and the Negative is connected to Earth. It is not shown in the datasheet (or I have not been able to find it there). How do I know? By measuring the Negative to the Earth pin in the AC input receptacle. I have seen similar units inside, and they simply have a wire, sometimes going through a ferrite bead, going from that PE to that 12V-.

I have used it successfully on one product without having connected the case to the 12V-. Successfully meaning, it passed compliance, both the immunity and compatibility.
However I'd prefer my case to be under Earth potential if possible, and for that reason I would like to know if anyone has considerations against it.

One way is to connect the 12V- directly to one of the mounting posts, holding the board to the case, the one right where the power enters the board. That is, the case will be electrically held to the 12V- which is also the Mains Earth GND at the same time.
The other is to connect it the 12V- to the same mounting post via a ceramic cap, say 0.1uF, and a 1M resistor in parallel. I also like to add an ESD clamp in parallel to the two.

PS. I am redesigning a product we have that is using a power supply that has Earth connected separately to the power connector's (4-pin DIN) shell. This is preferred, but this power supply is $65 vs $20 for the other. And the board barrel jack is $0.75 vs $12 for the Kycon DIN-4 they used before.

Comment: Just to be sure; how exactly did you measure that the output negative terminal is connected to mains inlet PE terminal? The data sheet claims isolation between input and output is at least 100 megaohms and can withstand 3000VAC between them. So they should not be connected at all.

Comment: And the datasheet is correct, only it means L and N, and not PE. PE is not really part of the Input. Some power supplys inside run a wire from the PE (often via a ferrite bead) right to the Vout-.

How I measured? With Ohmmeter, of course.

Comment: I would disagree. The Neutral wire will be connected/bonded to PE  wire somewhere in your building electrical system. I took apart one PSU brick, it had a 3-prong inlet but it had no Y caps from L&N to PE. PE wire went directly to secondary side, and was not directly connected to negative output terminal, but though a small capacitor (could be properly Y rated SMD cap) and also with few kohm resistor. So not 0R, not 1 Mohm. Weird. I also don't know the capacitance, the multimeter won't measure it due to the parallel resistance. The PCB allowed for direct bonding with 0R and ferrite beads, etc.